# Difference between .success() and .complete()?

Tags: jquery

As of jQuery 1.5, all jQuery's AJAX methods return a `jqXHR` object that provides `.error()`, `.success()`, and `.complete()` methods.

What is the difference between `.success()` and `.complete()`?

Comment: @nix do you have a link that describes the deprecated stuff in greater detail?

Comment: @neoneye Ctrl+F "deprecation notice" on api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JogVo.png

Answer (score 232, accepted):

`.success()` only gets called if your webserver responds with a `200 OK` HTTP header - basically when everything is fine.

However, `.complete()` will *always* get called no matter if the ajax call was successful or not - maybe it outputted errors and returned an error - .complete() will still get called.

It's worth mentioning that `.complete()` will get called *after* `.success()` gets called - if it matters to you.

- http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/
- http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/

Comment: .success is called when the server responds with ANY success status code `2XX`, like 200, 201,

Answer (score 11):

`success()` is called when the server returns a 200 status code, `complete()` is called always when the request is complete, no matter the outcome.

Answer (score 3):

`success()` is called when the server returns `success status code`, like: `200`, `201` etc.

`complete()` is called always when the request is complete. (no matter, it is success/error response from server.)

---

#### So,

- when there is `success` response from server: `success()` and `complete()` is called.
- when there is `error` response from server: `error()` and `complete()` is called.

---

**Example:** For what purpose you can use `complete()`: 
suppose in `beforeSend()` you show a `loader image`, and in `complete()`, you can hide that `loader image`.

Comment: complete is called AFTER success or error, so it would be clearer if you swapped the methods in your answer. E.g. success() and complete()

Comment: Thanks @Toby , I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`success()` called when server return *200* status code, `complete()` is called after `success()` . and i see some difference :

On `success()` you can't get xml response string that you get using `$.ajax()` and set `dataType:xml` 
But in `complete()` you can get string format of readed xml document using

```
$.ajax({
url:'??',
dataType:'xml',
oncomplete: function(data,status){
console.log(data.responseText);
}
})
```