# Jquery Ajax Post -> Works only when I step through the ajax call and only some times.......Any ideas?

Tags: ajax, visual-studio-2010, jquery, vb.net-2010

So, I have an ajax post that calls a service and returns an object which I want to parse on success.

I am running this in vs2010, it only works when I step through the ajax post code and it only works part of the time.

This call is basically identical to other pages that I have done so I am really troubled as to why this is not working.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: webMethod,
                data: parameters,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (obj) {
                    alert("Success");
                    parseStart(obj.d, id, idnum, parseType);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert("Failure. :" + e);
                }
            });
```

It is really standard, I am not sure why it is doing this.  I am just hoping someone has experienced something like this before.  Like I said it only goes through if I step through the ajax code and then it gets to the success.  If I do not step through it is as if it just never hits success or failure.....  It is really strange.  (so I do not see my alerts etc if I do not step through it)  I had a suggestion that it was possibly the size of my object that I was returning from my service so I trimmed that down to close to nothing and that did not help either.

Any thoughts directions on this are greatly appreciated.  I am currently stumped.

Comment: I believe that I have found that this is due to post that is happening in an internal method being called within the webmethod a post within a post I am posting another question regarding this as I am unable to delete this question.

Comment: And didn't want to create a rambling extremely off topic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after long long troubleshooting on this.  I switched the button call to the body onload versus a click of the button upon doing this it works without error.  This was due to me using an asp button that was producing a call back on click breaking my post.  I then removed my asp buttons and replaced these with an input button.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the server is not returning a 200. Maybe it's returning a 304 not modified or a temporary redirect.

See [Difference between .success() and .complete()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240876/difference-between-success-and-complete)

.success() only gets called if your webserver responds with a 200 OK HTTP header - basically when everything is fine.

However, .complete() will always get called no matter if the ajax call was suc

Comment: Good idea, added .complete() and still do not get an alert that I provided there.

Comment: Finally figured this out my answer is below.  Can't mark it for 21 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what it is. The ajax call is async, right? So it will take a period of time to get response. However if this call is generated via a link or form button and you don't return false here, then the normal get or post will occur. Just return false after calling $.ajax();

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: webMethod,
                data: parameters,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (obj) {
                    alert("Success");
                    parseStart(obj.d, id, idnum, parseType);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert("Failure. :" + e);
                }
            });
return false;
```

Comment: Tried this and no luck either.

Comment: have you tried using firebug in order to see what's happening on server? what if you put an alert before the $.ajax() method.. would that get called?

Comment: Yeah, I did this I get an alert there.  I tried IE step through and that is how I figured out that if I step through the entirety of the ajax call that it will sometimes work.  It really makes no sense....

Comment: hmm.. when it doesn't work, what are the values for webMethod, or parameters?

Comment: It is the same as when it did work.  The parameters are just a bunch of integers.  The webmethod is just the name of my webmethod these are basically just constants at this point.

Comment: how is the $.ajax called? what is it wired up to, if anything?

Comment: It is called via a button click.  (onclientclick event)

Comment: hmmm.. on a button click you probably don't even need to return false-- so I'm kind of stumped here. I think I would use firebug and see if my ajax call was being made to the server. My first guess was that it was redirecting before the ajax success call, but I might be wrong.