# Diplaying messages on ajax spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an ajax call and on success calling some more functions.
During the call I am displaying the spinner before and hiding it on completion.
I need to display some message with spinner like which function is getting called by success

`<div id="message"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>` is markup for spinner

```
function runAjax(){

    $.ajax({
        url:"demo_test.txt",
        beforeSend:function(){
           $('#message').show();
        },
        success:function(result){
           displaymessage1();
        },
        complete:function(){
           $('#message').hide();
        }
    });
}

function displaymessage1(){
    $('#message').append('This is message 1');
    displaymessage2();
}

function displaymessage2(){
    $('#message').append('This is message 2');
    displaymessage3();
}
function displaymessage3(){
    $('#message').append('This is message 3');
}
```

As soon as the "displaymessage1()" is called, I want to see the message on spinner and then for displaymessage2() and displaymessage3();

the problem is message is not appearing until the success function completes. Once success completes, messages appearing but within fraction of second it disappears as the ajax is completed.

I need to display it to create a processing effect so, that user will come to know that which method is running.

I have also tried by setting async:false, but still it was not helpful.

Please help, Thank You

Comment: Your function names don't match the calls you're making.

Comment: Where is the 'markup' for your spinner?

Comment: no...messages are appearing....but they are not appearing till the success block is finished...once sucess is finished they are appearing at once.

Comment: In the code you've given, the function names don't match the calls, and the give code won't work because there is an error in the object - there are no commas where they should exist.

Comment: <div id="message"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>

Comment: *"the problem is message is not appearing until the success function"* You are making the call inside the success function. I suspect what you you think the functions success and complete (deprecated) do is not what they actually do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240876/difference-between-success-and-complete

Comment: actually, the code above is dummy code. In real code I am getting a big JSON of about 33k lines which is getting parsed by the function which I am calling from success block.
check this url [link](http://oboejs.com/examples) and check the section titled "Giving some visual feedback as a page is updating"
I am trying to achieve something like this by using normal Ajax JS and Jquery

Answer (score 1):

Here I created code-snippet to track/log the statuses, you can also see **[Working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vpanga/w8v6L06k/)**

**Below code-snippet has JavaScript, CSS and HTML code blocks**
(You can run the snippet at the end)

```js
    //Assumption => delayTime [0: Start,    >0: Complete,    undefined: for_other_cases ]
    function displayMessage(statusText, delayTime) {
        var clear = function () {
            $("#state", this).empty();
        },
        $m = $('#message').show();

        if (delayTime == 0) clear.call($m);

        $('<li/>', {
            text: statusText
        }).appendTo($m.children('#state'));

        if (delayTime) $m.fadeOut(delayTime, clear);
    }

    function runAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: 'http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
            beforeSend: function () {
                displayMessage("Request Started...", 0);
            },
            data: {
              'text': 'some text',
              'text2': 'another text'
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            displayMessage("Request Processed successfully!");
        }).fail(function () {
            displayMessage("Request failed!");
        }).always(function () {
            displayMessage("Action finished and status message will be cleared in 3 seconds", 3000);
        });
    }

    $(function () {
        $("#testBtn").on("click", runAjax);
    });
```

```css
ul {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 2px dashed #999;
    padding: 10px;
}
ul>li {
    line-height:30px;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:1px dashed silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="testBtn" type="button">Click Me!</button>

<div id="message"> <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
  <ul id='state'>
    <li>Message Log... (this item only for testing)</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: actually, the code above is dummy code. In real code I am getting a big JSON of about 33k lines which is getting parsed by the function which I am calling from success block.
check this url [link](http://oboejs.com/examples) and check the section titled "Giving some visual feedback as a page is updating"
I am trying to achieve something like this by using normal Ajax JS and Jquery

Comment: Do you want to manage both displaying message and handling business logic by using the `result` with same method `displaymessage1`

Comment: the scenario is the moment "displaymessage1()" is called , I should see the message on spinnerbox and then when "displaymessage2()" immediately I should see the meesage of displaymessage2 on spinner and then for displaymessage3 nd after that spinner should hide as the ajax will be completed after displaymessage3()

Comment: I you have checked the link I have added in previous comment, and went through that section...you will come to know about what I want to do