# Parsing response text as key value pairs in an elegant way

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, json

Can't seem to find what I'm looking for in searches so this might be a duplicate but I haven't found an original yet sooo....

I have a an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/events/instructor/",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        instructorID: $(this).attr("id")
    },
    complete: function (data) {
        $("#name").html(data["responseText"]["name"]);
        $("#email").html(data["responseText"]["email"]);
        $("#photo").html(data["responseText"]["photo"]);
        $("#summary").html(data["responseText"]["summary"]);
        $("#url").html(data["responseText"]["url"]);
    }
});
```

The data being returned is encoded in JSON by the server (C#).

Obviously, `data["responseText"]["fieldName"]` isn't doing the trick. I could do splits and whatnot but that would mean that if the format changes, I'd need to make sure that the code above keeps up with the changed shape of the data.

How can I say something as simple as `data["responseText']["fieldName"]` to get the value out of that key?

Comment: i think you need to parse json first look at the http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: Hah, this gives me what I want.

                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data["responseText"]);
                    console.debug(obj.name);

Post your comment as an answer so I can give you credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to parse json first. look at the api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson

```
// data = '{ "name": "John" }'
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
console.log( obj.name);
// result will be "John"
```

P.S. also better use 'succes' instead 'complete', you can read about this here [Difference between .success() and .complete()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240876/difference-between-success-and-complete)

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log("response is good", data);
},
error: function (){
  console.log("something is went wrong");
}
```

Comment: Thanks and noted on the success vs complete

Answer (score 0):

try using like this:

```
complete: function (data) {
        var data=JSON.parse(data);
         $("#name").html(data.responseText.name);
        $("#email").html(data.responseText.email);
        $("#photo").html(data.responseText.photo);
        $("#summary").html(data.responseText.summary);
        $("#url").html(data.responseText.url);     

    }
```

to get only correct response use success.