# calling php from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying someting very basic and it doesn't work :
(Im getting the alert 'Test' and that's it :( )

```
<script name="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(part_id, product_id, type)
    {
        alert('test');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '2.php',
            data: {lname: "www", name: "Natalie"},
            complete: function (txt) {
                alert("complete");
                alert(txt);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

on 2.php I have only one line (on the same directory):

```
    echo "test has been run";
```

Comment: You have to initialize the type of request method you're going to use in 2.php

Comment: Wait, [check the console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome) for any errors.

Comment: Add firebug add on in to your firefox browser and check the console.

Comment: Can you change `complete` to `success`?

Answer (score 0):

use with `success` event.It will get  php result.

[**See the different between success() & complete()**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5240889/6235047)

```
<script name="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(part_id, product_id, type)
    {
        alert('test');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '2.php',
            data: {lname: "www", name: "Natalie"},
           complete: function (txt) {
               //do something
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert("success");
                alert(result);//test has been run
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax will return object data:

```
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "test has been run", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

You have to get response text from that object.

```
function myFunction(part_id, product_id, type)
{
    alert('test');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '2.php',
        dataType:'text',
        data: {lname: "www", name: "Natalie"},
        complete: function (txt) {
        console.log(txt);
            alert("complete");
            alert(txt.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it doesn't work for me. I probably missing something basic there.