# How to get value from AJAX responseText

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've got a AJAX function running which returns a response and I need to get the values from the responseText

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: process_payment.ajaxurl,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    action: 'process_payment',
                    payment_method_id: result.paymentMethod.id
                },
                complete: function(json) {
                    var response = json.responseText;
                    console.log(response);
                    handleServerResponse(json);
                }
            })
```

This is the contents of the variable response

```
{"requires_action":true,"payment_intent_client_secret":"0eo9ei48494404014044"}0
```

How do i the value of '`requires_action`' for example, i thought i could do `response.requires_action` but this returns undefined.

**EDIT**

This is also not working:

```
 jQuery.post(process_payment.ajaxurl, {
                action: 'process_payment',
                payment_method_id: result.paymentMethod.id
            }, 'json').done(handleServerResponse)

function handleServerResponse(response) {
    console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: Rename `complete` to `success` and use `json.requires_action`

Comment: use as `json.requires_action`, thle line `var response = json.responseText;` is not needed

Comment: Do i have to use success for this to work?

Comment: No, you could also use the `.done()` or `.then()` methods, eg `$.post(process_payment.ajaxurl, { action: 'process_payment', payment_method_id: result.paymentMethod.id }, 'json').done(handleServerResponse)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240876/difference-between-success-and-complete

Comment: @Phil  How do i then access the json object in handleServerResponse?

Comment: Eh? It's the first argument, eg `function handleServerResponse(obj) { console.log(obj.requires_action) }`

Comment: Hi Phil, sorry i may be missing the obvious here but i've just updated my question with what you're suggesting and it's not working. Forgive me, I'm not very experienced in javascript

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `success` callback instead of `complete` since `complete` keeps `xhr` object as a parameter in the callback or parse the response text to convert JSON string to object.

In case of `success` it will be parsed by default since you specified dataType as `json` and keep an error callback if necessary to handle the error case.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: process_payment.ajaxurl,
    method: 'post',
    // if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0 - use `type: 'post'`,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        action: 'process_payment',
        payment_method_id: result.paymentMethod.id
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        handleServerResponse(response);
    }
})
```

Refer :  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Might as well update to `method: 'POST'` to make it slightly more modern. Don't know how long jQuery will maintain `type`

Comment: @Phil : yes, but in older version there is no `method` option..... `type` is now keeping an alias to `method` now

Comment: @Phil : Anyways just updated :) Maybe they will remove in future ;)